# asp:RequiredFieldValidator makes postback with empty fields

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've faced the following problem with my aps validator. I have a textbox with asp validator. When the user leaves the textbox empty and click on the submit button the validation message shows, but the page does a postback. Any ideas what may cause this happen?

Heres  the validator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valReqName" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="blq blq">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    color: #4F4F4F;" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Many thanks,
Anton

**EDIT**

I have two tabs in an UpdatePanel. The validation problem is part of the second tab, where the user makes some inputs. When I've remove this trigger:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkUpload" EventName="Click" />
```

The postback problem was solved, but another problem occurred. Well at least the postback is removed. Thanks for all answers.

(lnkUpload is the id of the second tab linkbutton)

**EDIT 2**

Well here is the solution. It appears that my problem was the same like in this article. http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2011/08/08/validation-not-working-in-updatepanel/

Comment: Have you checked the CausesValidation property of the button in question? Is JavaScript diabled?

Comment: With CausesValidation = "False" and without it - still makes postback after the validation. I dont really understand what do you mean by "Is JavaScript desabled" I dont have onclientclick event on the submit button. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The page does a postback AFTER the validation message has appeared, or before?

Comment: @rikitikitik After the message has appeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting the solution as it might be useful for someone else.

"*This is the problem:
When a validator is loaded on the page it creates a bit of javascript to support the clientside validation. When you place a validator inside an usercontrol that isn´t visible by default, and this usercontrol is in an updatepanel, it does not create that javascript properly.
This is the solution:
Outside the updatepanel, I did above, create a dummy validator with a dummy textbox using a dummy validationgroup like so:*"

```
<%--dummy validator to make ajax validation possible--%>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="hidden" ControlToValidate="dummyTextBox" ValidationGroup="dummy"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dummyTextBox" CssClass="hidden"></asp:TextBox>
```

It appears that my problem was the same like in [this article](http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2011/08/08/validation-not-working-in-updatepanel/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the solution in this thread:

[ASP.net RequiredFieldValidator not preventing postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656098/asp-net-requiredfieldvalidator-not-preventing-postback)

Remove the following line from web.config

```
 <xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
```

"If I remove the line, my validation works the way I expected it to. Googling that uncovered a bunch of blog posts about how VisualStudio adds that line to the web.config when upgrading web apps from .net 1.1 to .net 3.5.

The blog posts were mainly complaining about how that field interferes with .net's AJAX stuff, but I'm guessing it messes with the JavaScript emitted for the RequiredFieldValidator in a similar fashion."

Comment: I don't have such a line in the web config.

Comment: Please post the markup for the submit button that causes the validation, maybe that is the culprit

Comment: Good to hear. Make sure to mark your own post as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I have to wait 6 hours to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Please add ValidationGroup to your validator(valReqName) and button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added validation group and still makes postback.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your validator.

```
 EnableClientScript="True"
```