# ASP.NET validation fails - displayed elements change visibility

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a client-side Javascript I use in an ASP.NET page to set the visibility of a couple of items in a datalist. Basically, when item 1 is visible, item 2 should be hidden and vice-versa. This code also enables/disables some ASP.NET required field validators depending on the visibility of the fields around them on the client side.

The code works fine *unless I have an ASP.NET validation error.* When the validation fails, the fields reset to their default visibility (hidden).

I've ruled out this being a postback since my server-side breakpoints don't get hit when the problem occurs. This seems to be something with the client-side script.

Server-side fixes are out since the page never posts back. I'm wondering how I can do this from a Javascript perspective? Is there a way to fire custom code when the validation scripts fire?

I thought about using a cookie, but I don't think that will help me unless I can hook into the validation event.

Code follows...

```
function handleDropDown(e, a, b, c, v1, v2, h1, h2) {
    var i = parseInt(c) + 2;
    var x = parseInt(c) + 3;

    if (e.value == "Yes") {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById(a).focus();

        //Enable validator if needed
        var oVal1 = document.getElementById(v1);
        var oVal2 = document.getElementById(v2);

        var oVis1 = document.getElementById(h1);
        var oVis2 = document.getElementById(h2);

        ValidatorEnable(oVal1, true);
        if (oVis1 != null) {
            oVis1.value = "true";
        }
        ValidatorEnable(oVal2, false);
        if (oVis2 != null) {
            oVis2.value = "false";
        }
       }
    else if (e.value == "No") {
        document.getElementById(x).style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById(x).style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById(b).focus();

        //Enable validator if needed
        var oVal1 = document.getElementById(v1);
        var oVal2 = document.getElementById(v2);

        var oVis1 = document.getElementById(h1);
        var oVis2 = document.getElementById(h2);

        ValidatorEnable(oVal1, false);
        if (oVis1 != null) {
            oVis1.value = "false";

        }
        ValidatorEnable(oVal2, true);
        if (oVis2 != null) {
            oVis2.value = "true";
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX Markup snippet:
**

```
             <span id="spTxtAnswer" class="required" visible="false" runat="server">*</span>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' runat="server" 
                                   TextMode="MultiLine" Height="76px" MaxLength="2000" Width="370px" Visible="false"  >
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valTextBox" ErrorMessage="This question is required." Enabled="false"
                        Display="Static" ControlToValidate="txtAnswer" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Request" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valAnswer" ControlToValidate="txtAnswer" ErrorMessage="<br />Other description is required."
                        Display="Static" enabled="false" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="Request" />
                        <span id="spDdlAnswer" class="required" visible="false" runat="server">*</span>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnswer" Visible="false" runat="server" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valDropDown" ControlToValidate="ddlAnswer" Enabled="false"
                        ErrorMessage="This field is required." Display="Static" runat="server"
                         InitialValue="(Select)"  ValidationGroup="Request" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestionID" Value='<%# Bind("QuestionID") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAnswer" Value='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRequired" Value='<%# Bind("Required") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfVisible" Value="false" runat="server" />
```

CodeBehind snippet:

```
TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 1].FindControl("txtAnswer");
            TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 2].FindControl("txtAnswer");
            RequiredFieldValidator rfv1 = (RequiredFieldValidator)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 1].FindControl("valTextBox");
            RequiredFieldValidator rfv2 = (RequiredFieldValidator)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 2].FindControl("valTextBox");
            HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 1].FindControl("hfVisible");
            HiddenField hf2 = (HiddenField)gridUserSupplierTypeQuestionsAndAnswers.Rows[rowIndex + 2].FindControl("hfVisible");

            ddl.Attributes.Add("onchange", "handleDropDown(this,'" + tb1.ClientID + "','" + tb2.ClientID + "','" + questionID + "','" + rfv1.ClientID + "','" + rfv2.ClientID + "'," + 
                "'" + hf1.ClientID + "','" + hf2.ClientID + "');");

            //When selected and viewing in edit mode, set the visibility during page load
            string script = "<script language='javascript'>";
            script += System.Environment.NewLine + "var el = document.getElementById('" + ddl.ClientID + "');";
            script += System.Environment.NewLine + "handleDropDown(el,'" + tb1.ClientID + "','" + tb2.ClientID + "','" + questionID + "','" + rfv1.ClientID + "','" + rfv2.ClientID + "');</script>";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),"startScript", script);
```

**

Comment: can you show a snippet of the aspx markup with the validators in place? i do suspect that your validation actually happens server-side. Did you put a breakpoint on the first line in Page_Load event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up needing to use a client-side script and a cookie to set the visibility. I need to persist values after a postback but read them client-side, so viewstate wasn't really an option in this case.

Another related issue was when I'd try calling the script to set the field visibility in IE10, it would always execute before the body finished loading. I set the call in the body tag in the master page, and it's working fine now.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I have offered an alternative answer to using cookies to track state of server-side values that can change client-side.

Answer (score 0):

From another stackoverflow issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11723794/704879):

"This is the problem: When a validator is loaded on the page it creates a bit of javascript to support the clientside validation. When you place a validator inside an usercontrol that isn´t visible by default, and this usercontrol is in an updatepanel, it does not create that javascript properly. This is the solution: Outside the updatepanel, I did above, create a dummy validator with a dummy textbox using a dummy validationgroup like so:"

Credits go to the original poster of the solution (Anton Belev).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but, just in case someone else comes across this like I just did, I wanted to provide an alternative to Tim's answer of using cookies to track state between the client-side and server-side.

If you have some javascript that needs to be able to read a value, such as whether or not a particular control has been made visible/hidden client-side, rather than use a cookie, I recommend creating your own view state in the same way .NET does.

I have seen numerous co-workers over the years attempt to throw a hidden field control into their page markup, but that is not always reliable because .NET can overwrite the client-side value when it reloads viewstate.  The solution I use seems to work very reliably, and isn't difficult to setup.  This works exactly the same for web user controls and even server controls.  This gives server-side and client-side access to the values across postback, and respects any client-side change to the values that might happen.

My example below shows a boolean, integer and string, but the same method can be used with any data type that can be serialized and deserialized to and from a "string" value.

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    const string
        hdnFld1Nm = "hdnFld1",
        hdnFld2Nm = "hdnFld2",
        hdnFld3Nm = "hdnFld3";

    protected bool HiddenFieldValue1
    {
        get
        {
            object vsVal = this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue1"];
            if (vsVal == null)
                return false;   // Whatever you want the 'default' value to be.
            else return (bool)vsVal;
        }
        set { this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue1"] = value; }
    }
    protected int HiddenFieldValue2
    {
        get
        {
            object vsVal = this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue2"];
            if (vsVal == null)
                return -1;  // Again, default value.
            else
                return (int)vsVal;
        }
        set { this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue2"] = value; }
    }
    protected string HiddenFieldValue3
    {
        get { return (string)this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue3"]; }
        set { this.ViewState["HiddenFieldValue3"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // For the boolean state, we'll consider any value other than "0" or NULL to be "true".
        this.HiddenFieldValue1 = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request[hdnFld1Nm]) && this.Request.Form[hdnFld1Nm] != "0");

        // For the integer, we have to parse from the string value we get from the Form collection, and deal with the potential for "null" if no value was returned.
        string sHdnVal2 = this.Request.Form[hdnFld2Nm];
        int iHdnVal2;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHdnVal2) && !int.TryParse(sHdnVal2, out iHdnVal2))
            this.HiddenFieldValue2 = iHdnVal2;

        // Getting a string value back is easy.
        this.HiddenFieldValue3 = this.Request[hdnFld3Nm];
    }
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Before the page actually renders, we want to let the .NET page renderer know that we want these three hidden field values written to the output page.
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(hdnFld1Nm, this.HiddenFieldValue1 ? "1" : "0");  // Make sure you keep your boolean logic the same.
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(hdnFld2Nm, this.HiddenFieldValue2.ToString());   // Hidden fields can only store "string" values, so we have to "ToString" our int.
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(hdnFld3Nm, this.HiddenFieldValue3);
    }
}
```