# asp.net web forms clientside validation always postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a brownfield site that fires asp.net clientside validation, whatever the result it always does a postback. Has anybody any ideas to stop this behavior if it fails the validation?

Thanks in advance.

Podge

Comment: Can you show us the code? If you've done everything correctly, it HAS to work.

Comment: Have you added a validation group to the control thats causing the postback?

Comment: Walther - I am afraid I cannot post anycode (due to privacy issues).  MrZulu - I have no validation groups.

Comment: Right after some further investigation it seems to be related to some url rewrites and an actionlessform, see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx#urlrewriting_topic7 (scroll backup). I now just to need to find a solution for the script side now.

Comment: This looks like a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656098/asp-net-requiredfieldvalidator-not-preventing-postback

Comment: The fix is here and it is related to the url rewrite.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656098/asp-net-requiredfieldvalidator-not-preventing-postback

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656098/asp-net-requiredfieldvalidator-not-preventing-postback

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Custom Validator control [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_customvalidator.asp) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) link. It allows you to perform client side validation. Usage [example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_customvalidator).

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Number not divisible by 2!" 
    ControlToValidate="txtCustomData" 
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidate" 
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckEven" /><br>
Input:
<asp:TextBox id="txtCustomData" runat="server" />
<script language="javascript">
<!--
function CheckEven(source, args) {
    var val = parseInt(args.Value, 10);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = ((val % 2) == 0);
    }
}
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry but it is not the issue of custom validators, but a postback is occurring even when the clientside validation has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same behavior and fixed it by setting the CausesValidation property to True.

Answer (score 0):

just for example: validate the textbox , if its empty postback not called else postback called.

button click event:

```
<asp:TextBox id="vTextBox" runat="server" />

<asp:button id="okButton" runat="server OnClick="okButton_Click" OnClientClick=" return isValidate();"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> 


function isValidate() {   var txt = $("#vTextBox").val();  
if ( txt === "") {  alert("error"); return false; }
else { alert(" no error "); return true; } }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a couple of CustomValidators where the ClientValidationFunction was missing.

Ensure there are no JavaScript errors on the page which could also cause this problem.

Answer (score -1):

For Client Validation you must be calling some JS function for validation:

If you are calling the client side validation method on a button click then you should call it like below:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id ="btnSubmit" onClientClick="return ValidateForm();" >
```

And the Validate Form method should return true or false.

like :

```
function ValidateForm()

{

/// Validation goes here 

if (validated)
{
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I am afraid none of the buttons have a onclientclick attribute added.