# TextMode.Phone doesn't do any validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my aspx page I have a textbox, which is placed on a modal window, together with an OK button:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="contactInfo" TextMode="Phone" ToolTip="Please enter your phone number">01234/567890</asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
```

However, the `TextMode="Phone"` doesn't seem to do any validation at all. Even if I enter absolute nonesense like "Hi, this is a text and definitely not a phone number" the page will not complain. If, for example, I change the TextMode to `TextMode="Email"`, then a message will appear asking me to enter a valid e-mail address and the modal window stays open, no matter how often I try to click the OK button.

Right now I have to validate the phone number on the client side (as changing the `TextMode` to `Number` introduces a whole lot of other problems), but I would like to use the "framework solution" just as I am able to with TextMode.Email.

Is the validation check really not implemented for `TextMode.Phone`? I couldn't find anything helpful regarding this topic.

Comment: Try to use `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<asp:TextBox TextMode="Phone">` is a .NET element that gets rendered into `<input type="tel">` HTML element and this HTML element does not automatically validate.

From MDN:

> `<input>` elements of type `"tel"` are used to let the user enter a
>   telephone number. Unlike `<input type="email">` and `<input type="url">` ,
>   the input value is not automatically validated to a particular format
>   before the form can be submitted — this is because formats for
>   telephone numbers vary so much around the world.

You can validate using a `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` with your desired regex.

For example:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revPhone" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Not a valid phone" ControlToValidate="contactInfo" 
   ValidationExpression="^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: `this is because formats for telephone numbers vary so much around the world.` But I think we can agree that they all use... numbers? Anyway, the RegEx will put out the message "not a valid phone", but it doesn't stop the postback from being sent, so the code behind gets executed regardless. How can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` prevents the postback by definition. If it doesnt it might be something with the regex itself (try a simple one just for testing purposes and after find/construct your own) or it might be something else about your form. Also you can try looking for answers such as in [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656098/asp-net-requiredfieldvalidator-not-preventing-postback)

Comment: Sadly, none of those answers helped, seems there is something different wrong with my project then. :(